# HibernateOptimisticLockingFailureException marks connection as 'closed'?

Tags: spring, hibernate, exception, database-connection, optimistic-locking

I'm getting the following stack trace:

```
org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateOptimisticLockingFailureException: Object of class [com.btfin.wrapcore.request.MFRequest] with identifier [2850448]: optimistic locking failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.StaleObjectStateException: Row was updated or deleted by another transaction (or unsaved-value mapping was incorrect): [com.btfin.wrapcore.request.MFRequest#2850448]
  at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.SessionFactoryUtils.convertHibernateAccessException(SessionFactoryUtils.java:672)
  at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateTransactionManager.java:793)
```

Which is due to an optimistic locking exception. I can address the root cause of this.

My question is - in this scenario - the exception handling sets the database connection to 'closed'. (Which causes issues with my connection pool).

What is the pattern for handling a database exception like `HibernateOptimisticLockingFailureException` that bubbles up through spring and hibernate and returns a closed connection?

Do you know the part in the Spring/Hibernate code that sets the connection to closed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Hibernate Docs](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/Session.html) clearly state that if *any* exception occur while working with the Session, the Session can't be reused afterwards. Moreover, each Session can encompass several transactions and after each transaction commits - the same happens, the connection is closed.

But while using a connection pool, the connection is not literally closed, when close() method is invoked, the [connection is returned to the pool without physical closing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/sql/PooledConnection.html):

> when an application closes its connection, the underlying physical
>   connection is recycled rather than being closed.

So if you have problems with the connection being physically closed, I would rather pay more attention to the pool, not to Hibernate or Spring - they can't do more than invoking close() which should work as I described earlier.